# The construction of my conditions in my function does not work. The program doesn't want to execute my condition?

Tags: javascript

In this function, the program does not want to consider my if condition. I stupidly tried to reverse the `if` and `else if`, but of course, that doesn't change anything.

I want that when the input value is < to 12000, the text-content of "amount6" be "no-qualified!". And when the input value is >= 12000, the text-content of the paragraphe "marginAmount6", be the operation's result.

HTML:

```js
function calcAmount6() {
  var userAmount5 = document.getElementById("amount6").value;
  var userAmount6 = document.getElementById("amount7").value;
  var oneLevel1 = 12000;
  if (userAmount5 + userAmount6 < oneLevel1) {
    document.getElementById("marginAmount6").textContent = "Non-qualifié!";
  } else if (userAmount5 + userAmount6 >= oneLevel1) {
    document.getElementById("marginAmount6").textContent =
      Math.round(userAmount5 * 13 / 100) + (userAmount6 * 5 / 100) + "€";
  }
}
```

```html
<p>CALCUL GAINS PILOTE QUALIFIE</p>
<p class="minimum2">(Points total minimum groupe conseillers + groupe animateurs = 12000 )</p>
<div class="blocklabel5">
  <label for="points amount" class="label6">Entrez points groupe 
    conseillers</label>
  <input type="number" class="amountEnter6" id="amount6">
</div>
<div class="blocklabel6">
  <label for="points amount" class="label7">Entrez points groupe 
    animateurs</label>
  <input type="number" class="amountEnter7" id="amount7">
  <input type="submit" value="Commissions pilote qualifié" id="submit7" class="submitEnter7" onclick="calcAmount6()">
</div>
<p id="marginAmount6" class="enterMargin6">0€</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Check the console, you may have an error somewhere and the JavaScript interpreter would bail out.

Comment: @PhilippeDelestan if you put a `console.log` for `userAmount5 + userAmount6` just before the `if`, and you put `11999` and `0` inside your inputs, you'll see it prints `119990` because you're concatenating strings, not adding numbers. The fact that your inputs have `type="number"` is irrelevant. Their values are still strings. If you happened to have them working in other parts of the code is probably because you were summing them to actual numbers.

Comment: Thank you very much. Actually, I've already used them in other parts of the code.I'm going to analyze this problem. I'm a beginner and it must show...

Comment: ...but it doesn't work ...

Comment: @PhilippeDelestan I tried adding a `* 1` at the end of the definition of `userAmount5` and `sureAmount6` as Jack suggested in his now-deleted answer and it actually works as I think it should. So either you didn't give us your actual code or your javascript engine is broken.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't tried everything of youre code.I'm really sorry to post 'it doesn't work'..I'm confused.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192565/discussion-between-philippe-delestan-and-federico-klez-culloca).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A) you use `<input type =" submit "...` and there is no form in your code; Submit is used to submit a page with the value of loading a new page in response.

B) `document.getElementById (" amount6 ​​"). Value;`returns a string ** and adding a string to a string is a string concatenation. ex "15" + "25" => "1525" as for any character string "hello" + "world" => "hello world"

C) prefer to declare your data pointers globally, this will prevent the interpreter JS from recalculating them with each click.

Here is your cleaned code:

```js
const
  in_amount6      = document.getElementById("amount6"),
  in_amount7      = document.getElementById("amount7"),
  bt_submit7      = document.getElementById("submit7"),
  p_marginAmount6 = document.getElementById("marginAmount6"),
  oneLevel1       = 12000;


bt_submit7.onclick = function()
{
  let 
    userAmount5 = in_amount6.valueAsNumber,
    userAmount6 = in_amount7.valueAsNumber;

  if ( (userAmount5 + userAmount6) < oneLevel1)
  {
    p_marginAmount6.textContent = "Non-qualifié!";
  }
  else 
  {
    p_marginAmount6.textContent = Math.round(userAmount5 * 13 / 100) + (userAmount6 * 5 / 100) + "€";
  }
}
```

```html
<p>CALCUL GAINS PILOTE QUALIFIE</p>
<p class="minimum2">(Points total minimum groupe conseillers + groupe animateurs = 12000 )</p>
<div class="blocklabel5">
  <label for="points amount" class="label6">Entrez points groupe conseillers</label>
  <input type="number" class="amountEnter6" id="amount6">
</div>
<div class="blocklabel6">
  <label for="points amount" class="label7">Entrez points groupe animateurs</label>
  <input type="number" class="amountEnter7" id="amount7">

  <input type="button" value="Commissions pilote qualifié" id="submit7" class="submitEnter7" >
</div>
<p id="marginAmount6" class="enterMargin6">0€</p>
```

AS I see your a French Guy:
Si on décompose l'instruction

```
var userAmount6 = document.getElementById("amount7").value;
```

on a:
1) créer une variable globale

```
var userAmount6
```

à chaque fois qu'on clique sur le bouton, ce qui n'est pas très bien, car ce n'est pas une variable globale, elle est juste utilisée **localement**, donc il faut la déclarer avec un  **let** .

2)

```
document.getElementById("amount7")
```

=> demander à l'interpréteur JS de créer un pointeur sur l'élément DOM `<input .. id="amount6">`, a chaque fois qu'on clique sur le bouton, c'est à dire que l'interpréteur devra répéter autant de fois cette opération à chaque fois qu'on clique,
alors autant déclarer ce pointeur en amont une bonne fois pour toute et en le déclarant comme étant une **constante** (**const**), car comme ça l'interpréteur sait qu'il n'aura pas à vérifier à chaque fois qu'il s'agit bien d'un pointeur sur un DOM ayant les bonnes propriétés désirées.
ce que j'ai fait ainsi:

```
const
  in_amount6      = document.getElementById("amount6"),
```

le **in_** est juste une regle d'écriture perso qui me permet de savoir que cela pointe vers un **input**

3)

```
.value;
```

=> utiliser le pointeur précédent et récupérer sa valeur textuelle.
Ce qu'en jargon on appelle une propriété ,(il y en a 1000 autres : la couleur de fond, la fonte utilisée, etc...)
comme cet élément est déclaré comme étant un nombre `<input type="number" ..` il possède aussi la propriété : `.valueAsNumber`  qui permet de récupérer sa valeur sous forme de nombre et non sous forme de string commme c'était le cas avant et qui te posait probleme.

une derniere chose: au lieu d'écrire

```
var A=15; 
var B='xyy';
var C=document.getElementById('...;
```

on ecrit une seule fois `var` ce qu indique bien qu'on demande à l'interpréteur JS de considérer tout ce qui suivra comme des variables, jusqu’à ce qu'il rencontre un point virgule.
et la syntaxe de  **var, const et let**  utilisent toutes les **simples virgules** pour distinguer les différentes déclarations.
ce qui donne

```
var A=15,B='xyy', C=document.getElementById('zID');
```

je les mets juste sur des lignes différentes pour que le code soit plus lisible

pour terminer:

```
bt_submit7.onclick = function() { ... }
```

correspond et remplace ton

```
<input id="submit7" ... onclick="calcAmount6()">
```

le principe est de ne pas *mélanger* le code javascript dans la partie body du html

j'ai pris soin de déclarer en constante le pointeur `bt_submit7` sur cet élément DOM, et l'instruction

```
bt_submit7.onclick ...
```

permet de "dire" que la fonction qui suit sert à récupérer tout evenement clic sur cet élément du DOM.
avant on utilisait cette syntaxe :

```
bt_submit7​.add​Event​Listener('click', function)
```

les références :
https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick
https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Comment: Thank you for this. I will test this solution, but i'm not understand  this code writing: _in _bt _p can you explain to me, please?

Comment: in_amount6, bt_submit7, p_marginAmount6 are just undeclared variables , isn't it? They are not a method of writing code, as I stupidly thought

Comment: in_amount6, bt_submit7, p_marginAmount6 are just undeclared variables. No, in_amount6, bt_submit7, p_marginAmount6 are **declared constants**

Comment: J'ai mis les explications à la suite de mon code précédent.

Comment: Yes, your explanations are precises and the code work here, but it do not work for me. Thank you very much for taking all this time to explain to me.

Comment: That is the error in my console with exactly the same code which you given me.Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null

Comment: sans doute parce que tu a placé le script js avant la partie body https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded

Comment: so ? did you manage to run this little script? and understood what was wrong in what you were doing to have such an error?

Comment: I've a file .js for my js. Finally, i use the "onclick attribute html" but i know that if i want to do the same thing with the "onclick in js", i will must use "window onload". Is that right?.

Comment: les navigateurs lisent les pages html ligne par ligne, en commençant par la première ligne. Si le javascript est placé avant le <body> le navigateur ne connait pas la nature de l'élément pointé par getElementById, puisqu'il ne l'a pas encore lu. soit tu place le JS a la fin du body, (juste avant </BODY> soit tu oblige le navigateur à interpréter le JS une fois la page entièrement chargée et tu utilise le `window.onload = function() { ....ici tout le contenu de mon script js ...}`